# django: which packages to use for billing plans, stripe and invoicing

Tags: django, stripe-payments, saas, recurring-billing

I want to add stripe based recurring payments, pdf invoice generation for each of those and 3 billing plans for a SaaS product. I'm using django/python: which packages are the best to glue together for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Silver looks interesting:

https://github.com/silverapp/silver

They have automated billing, payment processing, and PDF generation. This is not an endorsement; I just came across this question while researching a similar question.